# SPARQL queries equivalence issue?

Tags: sparql, sesame

(especially @JeenBroekstra)

Using the following graphs, I've got this SPARQL query that currently works on a Sesame repository:

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/sp>
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/spl>
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/spin>
FROM <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedysSPIN>
FROM <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys>

FROM NAMED <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys>
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {
        ?s ?p ?o .
    } .
    OPTIONAL {
        FILTER (sameTerm(rdf:type, ?p)) .
        ?o rdfs:subClassOf+ ?supC .
    } .
    OPTIONAL {
        FILTER (sameTerm(rdf:type, ?p) && NOT EXISTS { ?s a ?newSupC . }) .
        ?o rdfs:subClassOf+ ?newSupC .
    } .
    FILTER (bound(?newSupC)) .
}
```

Since both last optional patterns share some filter I figured I could merge them and I resulted to this query :

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/sp>
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/spl>
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/spin>
FROM <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedysSPIN>
FROM <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys>

FROM NAMED <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys>
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {
        ?s ?p ?o .
    } .
    OPTIONAL {
        FILTER (sameTerm(rdf:type, ?p)) .
        ?o rdfs:subClassOf+ ?supC .
        OPTIONAL {
            FILTER ( NOT EXISTS { ?s a ?supC . } ) .
            BIND (?supC as ?newSupC)
        } .
    } .
    FILTER (bound(?newSupC)) .
}
```

but when executing it, I get an empty resultset.

Thought to ask here before filing a bug request : could you tell me where the query is wrong or is this a bug in Sesame ?

Thanks in advance,
Max.

**EDIT :** I of course put the FILTER (bound(?newSupC)) just to expose the failing pattern. On the global scape, I still need all results even with variable ?newSupC unbound.

**EDIT :** Here are more details about configuration I use: 
Except for named graph http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys, I updated the graphs with RDFS entailment. The Sesame repository is a simple Native store without inference support.

Comment: I haven't determined yet if this is a bug or expected (though at first glance it looks like a bug), but before you log a bug report, can you try if you still see this problem with the latest Sesame release (2.7.10)? Since 2.7.2 there have been a number of bugs fixed in the SPARQL engine, at least a few of those were related to processing of OPTIONALs.

Comment: It's a fundamentally different query - OPTIONAL inside OPTIONAL is not like OPTIONAL after OPTIONAL.   BIND (?supC as ?newSupC) happens inside the inner OPTIONAL where ?subC is not bound (scoping) so ?newSupC is never bound and FILTER (bound(?newSupC)) is false always.

Comment: @AndyS having had another look I think you are correct. Perhaps you should post your comment as answer instead.

Comment: Jeen: updated Sesame to 2.7.10 and the result is the same
Andy: after some tests I finally understood what you meant and misused the BIND pattern.

Comment: @AndyS just to clarify some point that confused me much: the ?subC variable is in fact (and as expected) very bound in the inner OPTIONAL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thought I was sticking too much of trying to merge the two OPTIONAL pattern where 
the solution was much more direct :

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/sp>
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/spl>
FROM <http://spinrdf.org/spin>
FROM <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedysSPIN>
FROM <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys>

FROM NAMED <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys>
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://topbraid.org/examples/kennedys> {
        ?s ?p ?o .
    } .
    OPTIONAL {
        FILTER (sameTerm(rdf:type, ?p)) .
        ?o rdfs:subClassOf  ?supC .
    } .
    BIND (IF(NOT EXISTS { ?s a ?supC . }, ?supC, ?__unbound__) as ?newSupC) . 
}
```

Anyway thanks for you time and advice, guys.
Max.

Comment: You can use `UNDEF` rather than `?__unbound__`;  it's part of the standard.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks for the tip, I tried but it seems Sesame does not support it yet. Time to fill a feature request I think

Comment: Sesame does support this keyword, but according to the standard `UNDEF` is not allowed as part of an `IF` expression. It can only appear as a verbatim value in a `VALUES` clause.